# Is it necessary to close the connection explicitly when getting connection from Hibernate sessionFactory.getCurrentSession() for prepareStatement

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jdbc, sessionfactory

I wanted to insert some records using preparedstatement in Spring Boot application. So I have established the DB connection using hibernate(HibernateConfig - only for db connection). Since I'm going to use preparedstatement I acquired a `Connection` from Hibernate `SessionFactory` or `Session`.

I know that when using getCurrentSession will take care of the transaction management itself for hibernate operation like session.beginTransaction() and session.save().

Do I need to close the connection and other stuffs, explicitly in finally block when using `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()`? Kindly check finally block in the below code:

In DAOImpl file

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class TestDAOImpl implements TestDAO {

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public Connection getConnection(){
         Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
         Connection conn = session.doReturningWork(new ReturningWork<Connection>() {
                @Override
                public Connection execute(Connection conn) throws SQLException {
                    return conn;
                }
         });
        return conn;
}

public void insertRecords() {
     Connection conn= getConnection();
     PreparedStatement ps = null;
     try {
         String inserQuery ="INSERT IN TO TEST VALUES(?,?,?)" //some insert statement
         conn.setAutoCommit(false);
         ps = conn.prepareStatement(inserQuery);
         //set values ps.setString() and ps.addBatch(); -some code here

         int[] insertCounts = ps.executeBatch();
         conn.commit();
     } catch(BatchUpdateException e){

     } catch(SQLException e){

     } finally {
           if(ps!=null)ps.close();
           if(conn!=null) conn.close();
           if(sessionFactory!=null) sessionFactory.close();
 }
}
```

Please note that I'm using 3 more methods in same DAOImpl class and creating connection for each method `Connection conn= getConnection();` and closing in finally block.

Also let me know best practices or any other alternate way to get connection from SessionFactory.

Comment: Why are you using the session factory at all, why not inject the `javax.sql.DataSource` and get the connection from there? And I highly recommend learning about try-with-resources: it would simplify your code.

Comment: I have few questions when we use @Autowired private DataSource dataSource; for db connection. Correct me my assumptions, 1. In this case i should manually close all connections. 2. how can i read all  my hibernate properties like dialect. 3. transaction management is not possible here right. 4. how many max connections is possible with it. 5. how can i make sure all connections are closed, is there any way to find it. 6. is it best way for spring boot application

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you defintitely should close connections in order to prevent memory leaks.
Also the best approach would be a try-with-resources statement, which automatically closes the closable resources you opened within it.

```
try(Connection con = getConnection; Statement stmt = con.prepareStatement(insertSql)) {
...
} catch(Exception e) {
...}
```

You dont need the finally block this way, too.

EDIT: FYI if you don't close a connection it will stay open until you shut down the application, and each subsequent call opens a new one. I guess you can imagine what this means, when your DB only allows a maximum of 100 open connections at a time.

Comment: I agree, but when i use getCurrentSession() hibernate automatically controls the transaction close..no need to mention it explicitly. thats why i had a clarification here.

Comment: A transaction is not the same as a connection.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @MarkRotteveel, I removed hibernate config file and added below code

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {

    @Bean("dataSource")
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

}
```

In DAOImpl class,

```
@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

try(Connection conn= dataSource.getConnection();
       PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(inserQuery);) {
    .....
}catch(Exception e){
    ....
}
```

Please check and let me know if any modification required here.

Comment: How can i use connection pooling here for better performance ? any sample please